# Display channel entries using search:field_name across muitp[le channels

Tags: channel, search, entries

I need to be able to tell ExpressionEngine to display entries from multiple channels using the search:field_name parameter. The custom fields will be from different channel field groups (set to different channels). Here is an example:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="channel_1|channel_2|channel_3|channel_4" 
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc" 
    limit="6"  
    search:field_name_1_type="=field name" 
    search:field_name_2="=another field name from another channel"
}

    {!-- code --}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It should be. Have you tried it?